# How to create single table though class contains nested classes?

Tags: android, nested, ormlite

I am new to ormlite. 
My requirement is to create a single table, though it contains nested classes.

```
class Parent {
    String name;
    int age;
    Height height;
  }

 class Height {
    int feet;
    int inch;
  }
```

Here, Height should not be another table, rather it should be extended columns to Parent.

is that possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, Height should not be another table, rather it should be extended columns to Parent.
>   Is that possible ?

It is possible however not if you *also* want to store `Parent` or other sub-classes of `Parent` in the same table.  ORMLite does not support that pattern.

So you could have `class Height extends Parent` and have fields in `Parent` marked with `@DatabaseField` included in the `Height` table.

```
class Parent {
   @DatabaseField
   String name;
   ...
}
@DatabaseTable
class Height extends Parent {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Gray, thanks for the support. Here in my case, I am using jackson lib for json serialize/deserialize. So, I cannot change the class structure. It will break that one.